# Where do I buy windows 7 enterprise license

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am having a Windows 7 pro.. I need to buy a windows 7 enterprise license. Whats the best way and how do I get it if I am an individual and not a corporation.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Enterprise Licenses are purchased through the Volume Licensing division. The contact numbers and links to Volume level resellers can be found here http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/how-to-buy/default.aspx. Whether they'll sell only one license I don't know.

Comment: You usually need 5 licenses to get started.

Comment: @Joel I figured they wouldn't only sell one license but the license but wasn't positive.